# Split text file into smaller chunks

Tags: shell-script, ubuntu, command-line, split

I have a text file containing a list of strings. The strings are separated by newlines and have the same length, 8-digit. I need to split larger file into smaller chunks, where each chunk contains 4 strings, all strings in the same sequence as they are in a large file.

So I need to create 16 files, 15 files x 4 string each + 1 file x 2 strings. The files should be named as `list1.txt`, `list2.txt`, etc.

What is simplest way to solve this using tools such as `awk`, `sed`, etc.?

Comment: So many person are downvoting because it's so easy that no one thinks you tried to search it on duck duck go (or whatever) before asking. Please read again the first point of [How to Ask a good question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily use split.

```
split --lines=4 --additional-suffix=".txt" --numeric-suffixes inputfile list
```

where `inputfile` is, obviously, the input file.